# Keep element from moving when div appears on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On this page (which is made with bootstrap): removed
I have it set up so that you push the I - info button the left corner and a div appears with the user picture and description.

When this div appears, the graphic contained in the .mastfoot div moves up. I want it to be so that when I click the I info button and the div appears, that the .mastfoot does not move.

Any ideas on how to implement this would be appreciated.

Here's my code for the show hide button and div:

```
       <div class="container-fluid" id="foo" style="z-index:5; display:none; height:auto;">  
       <center>
       <div class="container-fluid" style="height:auto;">
       <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2" style=" margin-top:1%;"><img class="avatar-style-circle" src="{PortraitURL-128}" /><br/><h3>{AuthorName}</h3></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" style="background-color:blue; margin-top:3%;"><p style="text-align:justify;">{Description}<br/></p></div></div></div>

   <div class="container-fluid" style="height:auto; margin-bottom:2%;">
    <center>
   <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
    <br/>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">   <a href="{BlogURL}ask" button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Ask</a>

    <a href="{BlogURL}archive" button class="btn btn-default" button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Archive</a>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="z-index:5; margin-left:13%;">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 --></center>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="site-wrapper">
    {block:ifShowInfoButton}

   <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"><i class="fa  fa-info-circle fa-3x" style="position:absolute; margin-left:0.4%; margin-top:0.4%; color:{color:Info Button Color};"></i></a>


     {/block:ifShowInfoButton}
```

Here's the code for the .mastfoot :

```
<div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove position: fixed from the mastfoot, otherwise it will always stay in the same position, since it's positioned according to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is stated with the opposite intention.  Your question states that you don't want the image to move.  Currently the image does not move since it is "fixed".  Everything else moves.

Assuming you want the opposite of this action you can remove the following line of CSS from your file to allow the image to move with the rest of the page: `position: fixed; /** REMOVE THIS LINE **/`

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed; /** REMOVE THIS LINE **/
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
position:fixed;  bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what I believe you are trying to achieve try changing `#foo` to this:

```
#foo{
position:absolute;
background-color:#333333;
top:0;
}
```

and also add `z-index:100;` to your info button. This will prevent the background from pushing down when you open your info menu.

OR if I misunderstood and you want it at the bottom it could be this:

```
#foo{
position:absolute;
background-color:#333333;
bottom:0;
}
```